# How do I run a .sh script in Eclipse on Windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, shell, cygwin

On Linux, it was pretty easy.  I just did

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(shell location);
p.destroy();
```

But how do I do this in windows which doesn't natively allow .sh scripts?  I can get the script to run using Cygwin.  Is there a way I can somehow use Cygwin within Eclipse to run the script?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try adding the cygwin bin directory to your system PATH and then launch the sh.exe with the script as an argument.

Comment: I usually prefer mingw -- as processes [seem to] start much faster than cygwin, even if it's "less complete" of an environment.

Comment: How do you run sh.exe with an argument? Every thing I try complains about an error.  Is the format: navigate to cygwin/bin, do "sh.exe *args*" where args is the full file directory?

Answer (score 1):

Launching `sh.exe` (Cygwin, MinGW, or whatever) with the script as the argument is probably the best solution.

Another solution might be to update your folder options so that files with a `.sh` suffix are opened with `sh.exe`.